# What do I need to know about dungeons in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have always played World of Warcraft on my own; mainly because I don't play enough to build relationships with other players, and because I don't feel committed enough to having other start relying on me to log in every day / week.

Lately I am getting a little bored and feel like involving myself in the multiplayer parts of the game, like the dungeons, would make it more enjoyable.

Thing is, the game is filled with people who spend hour and hours playing and have tonnes of experience. I haven't used the dungeon feature before and I'm not that experienced in the game. I want to try the dungeon feature, but I don't want to end up annoying the other players by not playing well enough or as expected. I don't understand all the terminology that people use referring to items, skills or tactics. I also don't really understand a lot of the game mechanics that are more important when playing with others, like threat. I'm concerned about ruining the dungeon for others, which would deteriorate my interest in the game.

If I play a dungeon with others, what is expected of me? I suspect each class has its set of common tasks, but I don't know what they are. Are there some general rules / expectations that I can read about before I try it out? What is the worst thing I can do if I give it a go?

Comment: There's no harm in asking around. Everyone has to start somewhere, right?
It's like anything to be fair - Knowledge is there to be shared.

Comment: A couple of things that would help with giving an answer. First off what expansions do you have for the account? What level is the toon you are playing on that you are interested in trying dungeons with? Class and role also come into consideration when you start playing with others. Different things are expected of different classes. If you can get me that info I can give you quite a bit of advice for each role/class.

Comment: @Ravekner Well, I have Cataclysm at the moment. As for characters I have been playing my Draenei Shaman lvl 36ish but I also have a lvl 60 Troll Druid.

Comment: @MartyWallace The very first thing I will recommend you install via Curse(which has a lot of add-on tools for games like WoW) is Omen Threat Meter. This add-on will help you keep track of when an enemy is going to aggro on to you instead of your tank(when playing as a healer or DPS). This can become a big problem(DPS aggroing monsters) very quickly at lower levels for players new to tanking. Since you are playing your shaman, you have two roles you can fill while in a group, Healer or Damage Dealer(DPS). Healing is rather straight forward, keeping your tank alive is your #1 priority.

Comment: @MartyWallace If you can keep your tank alive, most enemies you find yourself fighting in lower level dungeons can be killed(even without the DPS alive). this unfortunately does not hold true to higher level dungeons, but can still happen with skilled healers and tanks. The main job of the DPS in a group is to KILL or LOCKDOWN enemies(meaning lots of Crowd Control abilites). It is often times better for the group to decide an enemy kill order before an encounter in dungeons, as this allows everyone to work together more efficiently and will cause less mistakes to be made during a fight.

Comment: @MartyWallace Those are the two roles you have available to your Shaman in a dungeon group(Kill everything or keep your allies alive to the best of your ability). Elemental and Enhancement shamans are both categorized as DPS specializations, while Restoration is the Shamans healing specialization. Unfortunately, I can't(or at least prefer not to currently) give you any more info about how each role should be played in a dungeon until I know which role you are planning on trying first. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a built in [Dungeon Journal](http://www.wowpedia.org/Dungeon_Journal) in World of Warcraft which can be accessed by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> which will give you a run down of the abilities that the enemies you will encounter in each specific instance possess, along with rudimentary tactics on how to deal with each ability. It's not comprehensive in terms of advising how to deal with an encounter but it will give you a head start on understanding what lies ahead.

[image: Dungeon Journal]

There are also many resources on the internet to provide information on how to complete dungeons. [Icy Veins](http://www.icy-veins.com/) has a lot of in depth information for all current instances (plus the instances from Cataclysm) which are [available here](http://www.icy-veins.com/dungeons-wow). This contains information on tactics plus a few hints and tips on how to complete each instance along with quest information and further information.

To optimise your performance I would recommend using an online class tool like [Noxxic](http://www.noxxic.com/wow) to get an understanding on what your skill rotation should look like, how you should reforge/gem/enchant, etc. This will increase your output, whether it be healing or damage, and increase your survivability as a tank.

For your first foray into WoW dungeons, I would recommend going in as a DPS rather than as a healer or tank. DPS, regardless of what many DPS say, is the *easier* role and is a bit more forgiving for a newcomer to dungeons.

The WoW community isn't the most friendly community in the world, as you've pointed out already there are many people in the game who simply don't have the time or inclination to teach newer players how to play, or get through an instance. Some people will be quite unforgiving if you make a mistake. Just keep this in mind when you're starting out and don't be put off by the actions of individuals and don't let it discourage you from continuing. Everybody was new once.

Comment: +1, but no mention of the in game dungeon guide? For a true beginner, that's going to be super helpful as well.

Comment: I had completed forgotten there was such a thing

Answer (score 2):

Most important of all you have to know theyre more difficult than the normal areas, secondly you have always to remember, that dungeons are GROUP-AREAS, what means no solo things, do not loot everything especially if you will never be able to use items and do not try to be a hero. Be polite and reliable, then you will get no problems ^^ and one more thing: if you are using plugins like curse-client or kinda that and you are using loot-plugins there, always deactivate autoloots... most people are getting angry when they get aware of that you are using one.

Answer (score 0):

When you join a group announce that you're new to dungeons.  There are groups of impatient people that will not want to teach you.  Those will remove (kick) you from the group.  Don't take that personally, they just want to run a quick dungeon.

Other groups will welcome you and as long as you try to improve, you'll be welcome.  It's worth queuing up a few times until you find the right group.

Having said that, dungeons have been awfully bland for years.  There's little threat and little feeling of accomplishment.  I think if you stayed out of dungeons, you've probably been enjoying the best part of WoW :)